# Different behaviour using php selenium on localhost or Jenkins

Tags: php, selenium, jenkins

I got strange case of using php Selenium once i use it on my localmachine and once pushed to Jenkins.

So i have this function

```
public function tableContent()
{    
    $data = array();
    $rows = TableBase::getAllTableRowsById($this->getWebdriver(), self::TABLE);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        //The problematic part
        $row->getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView();
        array_push($data, $this->getRowCellValuesByHeaderName($row));
    }

    return $data;
}
```

This function goes trough whole table and for each row it collects data. Then it  returns array of arrays of data. The problem is that getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView works OK and table scroller is moved once i run this code on my local machine. But when i commit the code to jenkins and then i watch my test on remote machine somehow getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView method is not working. The scroller isn't moved. So if view isn't scrolled all data is not collected and test fails.
So are there any limitations regarding the getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView on Jenkins? How come localhost test is working, but the same test is not working on Jenkins?

If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was rendering problem. Jenkins is running on virtual machine, so that's why code "get's" lost